Showing $M = i\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} u_{n}u_{n+1}^{\ast} - u_{n}^{\ast}u_{n+1}$ is conserved
The Ablowitz-Ladik NLS model is $$i \dot{u}_{n} = -(u_{n+1}+u_{n-1})(1+|u_{n}|^2)$$
This system has the conserved quantity $M = i\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} u_{n}u_{n+1}^{\ast} - u_{n}^{\ast}u_{n+1}$ per The Discrete Nonlinear Schrodinger Equation page $16$ by Kevrekidis. I want to show this is indeed the case.

Attempt:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}M &= i\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d}{dt}[u_{n}u_{n+1}^{\ast}]
 - \frac{d}{dt}[u_{n}^{\ast}u_{n+1}]\\
&= i\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} u_n'u_{n+1}^{\ast} + u_{n}{u_{n+1}^{\ast}}' - {u_{n}^{\ast}}' u_{n+1} - u_{n}^{\ast}{u_{n+1}}'\\
&= -\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(u_{n+1}+u_{n-1})(1+|u_n|^2)u_{n+1}^{\ast} + u_{n}(u_{n+2}^{\ast} + u_{n}^{\ast})(1+|u_{n+1}|^2) - (u_{n+1}^{\ast}+u_{n-1}^{\ast})(1+|u_n|^2)u_{n}^{\ast} - u_{n}^{\ast}(u_{n+2} + u_{n})(1+|u_{n+1}|^2)
\end{align}
What I expect to happen is the observation that the series is telescopic. However, I do not know how that is concluded. How can the above sum be rearranged so that the telescopic property can be observed? Factoring the $1+|u_{n}|^2$ (resp. $u_{n+1}$) terms doesn't seem to help.

You have a typo. In the third term in the final expression above, you should have $u_{n+1}$ instead of $u_n^*$. Also: You dropped the i.

Sorry, I see now that you didn't drop the $i$. But if you make the other correction and consolidate terms, the sum does indeed telescope.

Your last equation has a few mistakes. Since $i \dot{u}_{n}^* = (-i\dot{u}_n)^*=(u_{n+1}^*+u_{n-1}^*)(1+|u_{n}|^2)$, it should be
\begin{align}
\frac{dM}{dt}&= \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}[-\,(u_{n+1}+u_{n-1})(1+|u_n|^2)u_{n+1}^{\ast} + u_{n}(u_{n+2}^{\ast} + u_{n}^{\ast})(1+|u_{n+1}|^2) \\
&\qquad\qquad\!\!- (u_{n+1}^{\ast}+u_{n-1}^{\ast})(1+|u_n|^2)u_{n+1} + u_{n}^{\ast}(u_{n+2} + u_{n})(1+|u_{n+1}|^2)]. \tag{1}
\end{align}
Now, changing the index $n$ to $n-1$ in the terms $u_n(u_{n+2}^{\ast} + u_{n}^{\ast})(1+|u_{n+1}|^2)$ and $u_{n}^{\ast}(u_{n+2} + u_{n})(1+|u_{n+1}|^2)$, we obtain
\begin{align}
\frac{dM}{dt}&= \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}[-\,(u_{n+1}+u_{n-1})(1+|u_n|^2)u_{n+1}^{\ast} + u_{n-1}(u_{n+1}^{\ast} + u_{n-1}^{\ast})(1+|u_{n}|^2) \\
&\qquad\qquad\!\!- (u_{n+1}^{\ast}+u_{n-1}^{\ast})(1+|u_n|^2)u_{n+1} + u_{n-1}^{\ast}(u_{n+1} + u_{n-1})(1+|u_{n}|^2)]. \\
&=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}2(|u_{n-1}|^2-|u_{n+1}|^2)(1+|u_{n}|^2) \\
&=2\left(\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}|u_{n-1}|^2
-\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}|u_{n+1}|^2
+\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}|u_{n-1}|^2|u_{n}|^2
-\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}|u_{n+1}|^2|u_{n}|^2\right) \\
&=0. \phantom{\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}} \tag{2}
\end{align}
